# Nutch and Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nutch

I'm building a small search app using Elasticsearch, AngularJS and Nutch. I pretty much have the ES and AngularJS part complete. Now its time for the Nutch and ES part, using Nutch to crawl AND index the data into ES. I have been using Nutch 1.10 with ES 1.4. I've been using Nutch v1.10 to do some initial small crawls of about (~50 sites) on my local machine. I now see that ES is up to v2.3 or something like that and it seems that Nutch v1.11 STILL uses ES v1.4.

Does anyone have any experience with Nutch v1.10 working with any version of ES greater than 1.4 (maybe ES v1.5 or v1.7)?

I'd like to stay with the Nutch 1.x branch if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used Nutch along with ES 1.5/1.6/1.7 but there shouldn't be major changes between the API used by the `indexer-elastic` plugin. I've just followed the instructions in https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/src/plugin/indexer-elastic/howto_upgrade_es.txt and built/tested (`ant test`) Nutch 1.11 with ES 1.7.2 without any troubles. This means, that the code built ok, but I have not tested **indexing actual data** into Elasticsearch.

You'll have to build your own Nutch distribution, I do recommend keep your elasticsearch client version in sync with the ES server version.

Comment: thanks for the info and the link, do you have any plans to text the indexing of data? What version of ant did you use? I haven't used ant before...

Comment: Glad it helped, and yes I'm going to do a test crawl as soon as I download/install ES 1.7.2. Probably during the weekend :). Also, I'm using ant 1.9.6 at the moment.